# GitHub Copilot not working on company's network

Tags: python, github, pycharm, github-copilot

I have a problem with using GitHub Copilot on the company's network. At home it works perfectly, but every time I come to the office it doesn't work. It logs me out every time when it tries to generate something. The problem persists in all IDEs.

I assume it's something related to the network, do you know how to fix this?

I log in again and it immediately logs me out when I try to write something.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, this seems like a networking issue.

You should contact your IT department.

In the mean time, and **depending on your company's policies** you could try to connect to a different network (using your data plan for instance) or via a VPN.